# python file parser and checker

Tags: python

I have an input file for a specific CFD program.

This is a series of keywords:

```
+TURBULENCE MODEL
01222
+PH VALUE, MODEL=
7
```

and so on.

What would be the best way to check that the values are correct, or the keywords are not misspelled?

For example

```
+TURVULENCE MODEL
01222
PH VALUE, MODEL=2
7
```

Comment: How do you define "best"? Do you know *any* way that works?

Comment: For checking if strings or text are valid, RegEx is can be a good option. [Regexr](https://regexr.com/) is a good place to learn/tinker with it. However if you need more than simple string matching and actual *spellcheck*, then you'll need something more advanced

Comment: Also what determines "correct"?  Do you have correct values/spellings to refer to?

Comment: if you are trying to implement a domain specific language or grammar you probably want something like pyparsing

Comment: What if you just pass the file to the CFD program? It should hopefully complain if a file is not correctly formatted.

Comment: @Sam Dillard   yes , I know in advance how the  Keyword,Options, values  look like